# Cutting out and re-constructing string in javascript with substring

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I'm struggling with the logic...suppose I have this string:

```
var s = '<span>foo bar</span><img src="www.foo.bar"><img src="www.blah.blah">
<span>blah blah blah</span>';
```

What I want to do is cut out the sources of each image and reconstruct the "s" string without the image sources.  Here's what I have so far but it's wrong...

```
numImgs = s.match(/<img/gi).length;
    if (numImgs > 0) {
        var imgSrc, startSrc = 0, endSrc = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < numImgs; i++) {
            (function() {
                startSrc = s.indexOf('<img src="', endSrc);
                endSrc = s.indexOf('"', startSrc + 10);
                imgSrc = s.substring(startSrc+10, endSrc);
                s = s.substring(0, startSrc+10) + s.substring(endSrc, s.length);
                console.log("start: " + startSrc + " end: " + endSrc + "\n" + s);
            })(i);
        }
    }
```

I understand I can't use `s.indexOf('<img src="', endSrc)` for the start because second time the "s" string has changed and `endSrc` is way off.  How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here, to get the second, third, fourth `img`?

The result would be:

```
var s = '<span>foo bar</span><img src=""><img src=""><span>blah blah blah</span>';
```

SOLUTION: this is probably a very dirty way of doing this but for what I have, I added `startSrc = s.indexOf('<img src="data');` so it will find the first occurrance of a `src` which is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = '<span>foo bar</span><img src="www.foo.bar"><img src="www.blah.blah"><span>blah blah blah</span>';

var srcArray = [];
var result = s.match(/(<img).+?(>)/gi);

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var src = result[i].match(/src=\"(.+?)\"/);
    srcArray.push(src[1]);    
}
s = s.replace(/(<img).+?(>)/gi,'<img src=""/>');
console.log(srcArray, s); //["www.foo.bar", "www.blah.blah"] "<span>foo bar</span><img src=""/><img src=""/><span>blah blah blah</span>"
```

Comment: That would work if I didn't need to get the image sources before...but I need them (base64 image src which need to be uploaded...big files)

Comment: Edited my answer. Now the src attributes stored in an array